# Can I install elementary OS on my dell xps 13 9350 now?

Tags: release-freya

I'm new to Linux. I want to dual boot elementary OS and windows 10 on my dell xps 13 which has QHD+ resolution and skylake processor. Is it ok?

Comment: I'm curious too, heard there are plenty of issues without about a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Since Elementaryos is based on Ubuntu you should be ok.
Check this page by Ubuntu : http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201508-18805/.
More information regarding dual boot can also be found on the Ubuntu site here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot.